# Rails find records tagged with multiple tags | undefined method 'where' for Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags

So I want to build a jobsboard, with jobs which are tagable.
I want to implement it by myself, so I followed this tutorial:
https://www.sitepoint.com/tagging-scratch-rails/

all works, but i want to get not only all jobs which are tagged with one tag (the tutorial has a method for that `tagged_with(name)` ) but instead I want to get all jobs which are tagged with multiple tags.

So i added a method to the `job.rb` model as followed:

```
def self.tagged_with_tags(tags)
    jobs = []
    tags.each do |tag|
        Jobtag.where(name: tag).first.jobs.map do |j|
            jobs.push(j) unless jobs.include?(j)
            puts j
        end
    end
    jobs
end
```

That seems to work, but I want to query the returned array further like:

```
@jobs = Job.tagged_with_tags(@tags).where(category: 'Full-Budget').order('created_at desc')
```

And here I get this Error:
**`undefined method 'where' for #<Array:0x007fb1b0a25c10>`**

---

Here are my models:

**job.rb**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :jobtags, through: :taggings

    def all_jobtags=(names)
        self.jobtags = names.split(",").map do |name|
            Jobtag.where(name: name.strip.downcase).first_or_create!
        end
    end

    def all_jobtags
        self.jobtags.map(&:name).join(", ")
    end

    def self.tagged_with(name)
        Jobtag.find_by_name!(name.downcase).jobs
    end

    # Needs work:
    def self.tagged_with_tags(tags)
        jobs = []
        tags.each do |tag|
            Jobtag.where(name: tag).first.jobs.map do |j|
                jobs.push(j) unless jobs.include?(j)
                puts j
            end
        end
        jobs
    end

end
```

**Jobtag.rb**

```
class Jobtag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :jobs, through: :taggings
end
```

**Tagging.rb**

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job
    belongs_to :jobtag
end
```

Comment: You can not call `where` clause on array class.

Comment: yes, but how to I get a collection of jobs where I can call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the desired result with active record joins query.
Iterating through each job objects and pushing it to array is less efficient.

```
@tags = ['tag_name1', 'tag_name2']
```

Something like this:

```
@jobs = Job.joins(:jobtags).where(jobtags: { name: @tags }).
          where(category: 'Full-Budget').
          order('created_at desc')
```

**Update**

If you want to fetch jobs which have all the tags listed in @tags array, check count of jobtags in the same query.

```
@jobs = Job.joins(:jobtags).where(jobtags: { name: @tags }).
          group('jobs.id').
          having('count(jobs.id) = ?', @tags.size).
          where(category: 'Full-Budget').
          order('created_at desc')
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Hmmm I am not sure, it kinda works, had to change `:job_tags` to `jobtags` but I think the problem is that I get all Jobs with either tag from the @tags array, but I want to get only the jobs which have both @tags

Comment: That was not your question. Also the method(self.tagged_with_tags(tags)) you have tried won't give job results which has both tags. Update your question.

Comment: So, how would I find only Jobs results which only have both @tags?

Comment: Oh, I think it actually works now as intended, had two tags with the same name ... Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

To use `.where` you need to have a ActiveRecord collection.

```
Job.joins(:job_tags).where("jobs_tags: { name: "name of tag or array of tag names").where(category: 'Full-Budget').order('created_at desc')
```