# how to match all multiple conditions with rails where method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using active record, I want to perform a lookup that returns a collection of items that have ALL matching id's.

Given that the below example matches on ANY id in the array, I am trying to figure out the syntax so that it will match when ALL of the id's match. (given that in this example there is a many to many relationship).

The array length of the id's is also variable which prohibits chaining .where()

```
x.where(id: [1,2])
```

Note: this question got removed before and there are a lot of answers for performing a sql "where in" but this question is about performing a sql "where and"

Comment: `where(id: [1,2])` doesn't make sense unless you're joining to an association table and in that case, the duplicate from yesterday solves your problem: "where in" combined with HAVING. How is this question different than [the "duplicate" from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771944/rails-find-records-tagged-with-multiple-tags-undefined-method-where-for-arra) and why can't you use the standard "WHERE IN and HAVING" approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exec_query` and execute your own bound query:

```
values          = [1, 2]
where_condition = values.map.with_index(1) { |_, index| "id = $#{index}" }.join(" AND ")
sql             = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE #{ where_condition }"
binds           = values.map { |i| ActiveRecord::Relation::QueryAttribute.new(nil, i, ActiveRecord::Type::Integer.new) }

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql, nil, binds)
```

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with @muistooshort's comment

> `where(id: [1,2])` doesn't make sense unless you're joining to an association table and in that case,..."where in" combined with HAVING [solves your problem].

But for the sake of answering the question and the assumption that `id` was just and example.

While @SebastianPalma's answer will work it will return an `ActiveRecord::Result` whereas most of the time the desire is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

We can achieve this by using `Arel` to build the `where` clause like so:
(*I modified the example to use `description` rather than `id` so that it makes more logical sense*)

```
table = MyObject.arel_table 
values = ['Jamesla','Example']
where_clause = values.map {|v| table[:description].matches("%{v}%")}.reduce(&:and)
# OR 
where_clause = table[:description].matches_all(values.map {|v| "%#{v}%"})
MyObject.where(where_clause)
```

This will result in the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
  my_objects.* 
FROM 
  my_objects
WHERE 
  my_objects.description LIKE '%Jamesla%' 
  AND my_objects.description LIKE '%Example%'
```

Comment: Or `MyObject.where(expr1).where(expr2)...` built using `exprs.inject(MyObject) { |q, expr| q.where(expr) }`.

Comment: @muistooshort true and since the question was technically about equality your solution would be preferential; however as you so poignantly pointed out the condition itself is completely illogical as it is currently stated.

Comment: But I think LIKE might be closer to the real intent. Or maybe it is the "object has all these tags" question in disguise. Maybe. Just for fun, if this was PostgreSQL you could `where('x like all(array[?])', ['%Jamesla%', '%Example%'])` and such.

Comment: @muistooshort in that case just for fun `table[:description].matches(Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('ALL',[Arel.sql("array[#{values.map {|s| "'%#{s}%'"}.join(',')}]")])).to_sql #=> "[my_objects].[description] LIKE ALL(array['%Jamesla%','%Example%'])"`